# Load external data into div n second after click - once

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I want to load the external data into div for 1 second after click **ONLY ONE TIME**.

I have my code. It works but when an id of a button is clicked. The loop begins like eternity. The data keeps sending again and again. I want only once after a button is clicked.

Here is my code.

```
$(".log_bak").load('inc/log_bak.php'); 
$("#log_bak_btn").click(function(){
            setInterval(function(){
          $.ajax({    //create an ajax request to load_page.php
            type: "POST",
            url: "inc/log_bak.php",             
            dataType: "html",   //expect html to be returned                
            success: function(response){                    
                $(".log_bak").html(response); 
            }
        });//ajax
    }, 10000);
});//click
```

Comment: [`one()`](http://api.jquery.com/one/) could potentially work for this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `setInterval` use `setTimeout`, The setInterval() method will continue calling the function until clearInterval() is called, or the window is closed. Whereas the setTimeout() method calls a function or evaluates an expression after a specified number of milliseconds and is executed only once.

And use `$("#log_bak_btn").off('click');` to remove the click event.

```
$("#log_bak_btn").click(function() {

  $("#log_bak_btn").off('click');// Remove click event

  setTimeout(function() {
    $.ajax({ 
      type: "POST",
      url: "inc/log_bak.php",
      dataType: "html",          
      success: function(response) {
        $(".log_bak").html(response);
      }
    }); 
  }, 10000);
});
```

Comment: I need `$(".log_bak").load('inc/log_bak.php'); ` - it is a pre-load into the `.log_bak` div.

Comment: your answer is correct, I'll accept it soon (the system says I need to hold my kind after 5 mins.)

Comment: @Wilf haha no deal here. :P

Answer (score 1):

Use `on` and `off` methods of the `jQuery`. `on` is used to `attach` a chick event and `off` will remove the `event` from the element.

**Edit:** You can use `.load` to get the `html` parsed data in `.log_bak` container. `.one()` => Attach a handler to an event for the elements. The handler is executed at most once per element per event type.

```js
$(".log_bak").load('inc/log_bak.php');
$("#log_bak_btn").one('click', function() {
  setInterval(function() {
    $(".log_bak").load('inc/log_bak.php');
  }, 10000);
});
```